# mysql 1 month record join another table

Tags: mysql

I added 30 days records in mycalendar

```
INSERT INTO mycalendar (myday) VALUES ('2022-06-01'),('2022-06-02'),('2022-06-03'),('2022-06-04'),('2022-06-05'),('2022-06-06'),('2022-06-07'),('2022-06-08'),('2022-06-09'),('2022-06-10'),('2022-06-11'),('2022-06-12'),('2022-06-13'),('2022-06-14'),('2022-06-15'),('2022-06-16'),('2022-06-17'),('2022-06-18'),('2022-06-19'),('2022-06-20'),('2022-06-21'),('2022-06-22'),('2022-06-23'),('2022-06-24'),('2022-06-25'),('2022-06-26'),('2022-06-27'),('2022-06-28'),('2022-06-29'),('2022-06-30')
```

I want display 1 month calendar, 30 day in that month

| Staff | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| User2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

```
SELECT * FROM attTable 
JOIN mycalender ON date(attTable.TimeIN) = date(mycalender.myday) 
WHERE attTable.EMPID ='100003' ORDER BY attTable.EMPID;
```

I tried left join, right join, inner join but i can not get 30 days
[image: calendar]

Comment: We do not know what is in `attTable` - is it possible that you do not have sufficient records to return 30 given that join and where clause?

Comment: attTable for Ateendance

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. You added 30 records to `mycalendar` table - OK. You have another table (`attTable`) but we do not know what records are in that table - it seems that you do not have sufficient records to fulfill the stated criteria given by the `where` clause and that particular table `join`

Comment: dear sir, i hope you can see image attTable, there is EMPID, TimeIN, TimeOUT, OTM records available, I want to make if employee absent it should be 0, if present it should be 1, then i can count total absent total present, so mycalender table all records should be join, if absent it will be blank or zero, my current mysql statement join only if both match.

Comment: The output which you need in is pivot table. MySQL does not support it. Search by "[mysql] pivot" - there is a lot of solutions. Or transform your data on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 100003 AS EMPID , myday, CASE WHEN TimeIn IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS present FROM mycalender  LEFT JOIN attTable ON DATE(mycalender.myday) = DATE(attTable.TimeIn) WHERE EMPID = '100003' OR EMPID IS NULL